# Windows Phone 8: Add a "check" over an image

Tags: image, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a  control and I want to add a "check" in the top right corner of the image. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: look that check part is property of gridview and listview controls. and if you really want to do that you have to use some workaround like take a grid and set its bacbground to that image and then a check image on the right most corner of thatgrid and set the visibility according to your use

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this [Sample](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D388A3652195E9E8!210&authkey=!ABEtaDIZ-odTsOw), This Sample contain images with checkboxes.

These Checkboxes are customized, set the property IsChecked to true always if you want to add a check on the Images.